# java struts radio button value is updating to null instead of N in database

Tags: jsp, struts-1

Hello I am trying to update radio button value in database. 
I have two options here "Y" and "N". When I select N, in database it is updating to NULL instead of "N".

Here is the code.

ExternalSystem.java

```
public class ExternalSystem extends ModelWritable {
    private String externalSystemId;
    private Boolean enabled;

//getter/setter
}
```

ExternalSystemActionForm.java

```
public class ExternalSystemActionForm extends VistaActionForm {
      private List<ExternalSystemDTO> externalSystems;
      private String externalSystem;
      // amend stuff
      private String amendEnabled;
      // authority
      private Boolean hasAmendAuthority = Boolean.FALSE;

      public List<ExternalSystemDTO> getExternalSystems() {
          return externalSystems;
      }

      public void setAmendEnabled(String amendEnabled) {
    this.amendEnabled = amendEnabled;
}

public String getAmendEnabled() {
    return amendEnabled;
}
public Boolean getHasDeleteAuthority() {
    return hasDeleteAuthority;
}

public void setHasAmendAuthority(Boolean hasAmendAuthority) {
    this.hasAmendAuthority = hasAmendAuthority;
}
}
```

ExternalSystemDispatchAction.java

```
    public class ExternalSystemDispatchAction extends VistaDispatchActionBase {

public ActionForward amend(ActionMapping mapping, ActionForm form, 
    HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {

    BrandMarketReferenceBusinessDelegate delegate = new 
BrandMarketReferenceBusinessDelegate();
    ExternalSystemActionForm actionForm = (ExternalSystemActionForm) form;      

    // Do 'Amend' Stuff

    ExternalSystemDTO amendDTO = new ExternalSystemDTO(new ExternalSystem());
    amendDTO.setExternalSystemId(actionForm.getExternalSystem());

    amendDTO.setEnabled(actionForm.getAmendEnabled());
    amendDTO.setTimezoneName(actionForm.getAmendTimezone());

    actionForm.setErrorMessage(delegate.amendExternalSystem(amendDTO, getUser()));


    populateCurrentData(delegate, actionForm);
    for (ExternalSystemDTO dto : actionForm.getExternalSystems()) {
        dto.setBeingAmended(false);
    }

    final ActionForward forward = mapping.findForward("success");

    return forward;
}
}
```

ExternalSystemDTO.java

```
public class ExternalSystemDTO {

private ExternalSystem externalSystem;
private boolean isBeingAmended = false;


public ExternalSystemDTO (ExternalSystem externalSystem) {
    this.externalSystem = externalSystem;
}

public String getEnabled() {
    return externalSystem.getEnabled() ? "Y" : "N";
}

public void setEnabled(String enabled) {
    externalSystem.setEnabled(enabled.equals("Y"));
}
}
```

externalSystemMaint.jsp

```
  <script>
  function selectButton(externalSystem){
  document.forms.ExternalSystemForm.method.value="select";
  document.forms.ExternalSystemForm.externalSystem.value=externalSystem;
  document.forms.ExternalSystemForm.submit();
 }  

  function amendButton(externalSystem){
  document.forms.ExternalSystemForm.method.value="amend";
  document.forms.ExternalSystemForm.externalSystem.value=externalSystem;
  document.forms.ExternalSystemForm.submit();
 }  

</script>


  <!-- This row has previously been selected for update so show data in a way that it can be amended -->

    <logic:equal name="externalSystem" property="beingAmended" value="true"> 
        <logic:equal name="externalSystem" property="enabled" value="Y">
            <td class="borderedCell">Y<input name="amendEnabled" type="radio" value="Y" checked></input>
        </logic:equal>
        <logic:notEqual name="externalSystem" property="enabled" value="Y">
            <td class="borderedCell">Y<input name="amendEnabled" type="radio" value="Y"></input>
        </logic:notEqual>
        <logic:equal name="externalSystem" property="enabled" value="Y">              
            N<input name="amendEnabled" type="radio" value="N" ></input></td>
        </logic:equal>
        <logic:notEqual name="externalSystem" property="enabled" value="Y">              
            N<input name="amendEnabled" type="radio" value="N" checked></input></td>
        </logic:notEqual>   
        <!-- Eventually make this a drop down based on the vista_external_system table -->             
        <td class="borderedCell"><input name="amendTimezone" type="text" value="<bean:write name="externalSystem" property="timezoneName"/>"></input></td>
        <td class="borderedCell" align="center">
        <!-- In theory should not get this far if they haven't got authority but what the heck -->
        <logic:equal name="ExternalSystemForm" property="hasAmendAuthority" value="true">            
            <html:img src="images/select2.gif" onclick='<%= "amendButton(" + MessageUtils.encodeJSConstant(externalSystem.getExternalSystemId()) + ")" %>' />
         </logic:equal>
```

Can somebody please help me with this.

Answer (score 0):

Browsers send the value only if a radio button property is `checked` and send **nothing** if a radio button property is `unchecked`.

That means the setter `setAmendEnabled` is not called if a radio button property is `unchecked` and the value of `amendEnabled` remains `null`. Try to assign the default value for `amendEnabled`:

```
public class ExternalSystemActionForm extends VistaActionForm {
    ...
    private String amendEnabled = "N";
```

Comment: Hi @sergey Thanks for the answer. I tried assigning default value to amendEnabled variable but still I am getting NULL value in database.